# OpenGL texture form HLS video on iOS

Tags: ios, video, opengl-es

I'm trying to use the HLS video as a texture in the `GLKView`. I'm setting a video output like this:

```
NSDictionary* settings = @{
                           (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange],
                           (id)kCVPixelBufferOpenGLCompatibilityKey : [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                           };

self.videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:settings];
[self.videoOutput requestNotificationOfMediaDataChangeWithAdvanceInterval:ONE_FRAME_DURATION];
[playerItem addOutput:self.videoOutput];
```

When the output reports new data arriving, I extract it like this:

```
outputItemTime = [self.videoOutput itemTimeForHostTime:nextVSync];  // this is calculated from the timestamps
if ([self.videoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:outputItemTime]) {
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
      pixelBuffer = [self.videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:outputItemTime itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];
```

Pixel buffer appears in the logs like this:

```
<CVPixelBuffer 0x146d1b50 width=1024 height=680 pixelFormat=420v iosurface=0x1657fb24 planes=2>
<Plane 0 width=1024 height=680 bytesPerRow=1024>
<Plane 1 width=512 height=340 bytesPerRow=1024>
<attributes=<CFBasicHash 0x145da410 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = immutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
  0 : <CFString 0x3b8cac84 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "Width"} = <CFNumber 0x145c2260 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = +1024.0000000000, type = kCFNumberFloat32Type}
  1 : <CFString 0x3b8cb134 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "OpenGLCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x3b84ae90 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = true}
  3 : <CFString 0x3b8cb154 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "IOSurfaceProperties"} = <CFBasicHash 0x145d9e40 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
  2 : <CFString 0x3b8cada4 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "IOSurfacePurgeWhenNotInUse"} = <CFBoolean 0x3b84ae90 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = true}
}

  5 : <CFString 0x3b8cb0e4 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "PixelFormatType"} = <CFNumber 0x145c2160 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = +875704438, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
  6 : <CFString 0x3b8cac94 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "Height"} = <CFNumber 0x145c2270 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = +680.0000000000, type = kCFNumberFloat32Type}
}
 propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x146d1bb0 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 7,
entries =>
  0 : <CFString 0x3b8caff4 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0x146aef90 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
  1 : <CFString 0x3b8caf74 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x146d1b30 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
  3 : <CFString 0x3b8cb014 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField"} = <CFString 0x3b83d1d0 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "Center"}
  9 : <CFString 0x3b8cb024 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationBottomField"} = <CFString 0x3b83d1d0 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "Center"}
  10 : <CFString 0x3b8cafb4 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x146d1b10 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
  11 : <CFString 0x3b8caeb4 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "CVFieldCount"} = <CFNumber 0x1458d890 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = +1, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
  12 : <CFString 0x1467cb60 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "QTMovieTime"} = <CFBasicHash 0x146c6010 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
  0 : <CFString 0x14687e80 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "TimeValue"} = <CFNumber 0x1458d3b0 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
  2 : <CFString 0x146df3e0 [0x3b84aae0]>{contents = "TimeScale"} = <CFNumber 0x146c6040 [0x3b84aae0]>{value = +90000, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x1468f700 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
```

I then extract the textures from the buffer like this:

```
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             _videoTextureCache,
                                             pixelBuffer,
                                             NULL,
                                             GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                             GL_RED_EXT,
                                             frameWidth,
                                             frameHeight,
                                             GL_RED_EXT,
                                             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                             0,
                                             &_lumaTexture);

CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                             _videoTextureCache,
                                             pixelBuffer,
                                             NULL,
                                             GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                                             GL_RG_EXT,
                                             frameWidth / 2,
                                             frameHeight / 2,
                                             GL_RG_EXT,
                                             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                                             1,
                                             &_chromaTexture);
```

They appear in the logs like the following. Luma:

```
< CVOpenGLESTextureRef 0x19d7d210 size=1024,680 target=0de1 name=1 isFlipped=YES propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x19d7f1f0 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x19d7e180 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
```

Chroma:

```
< CVOpenGLESTextureRef 0x19d7d2a0 size=1024,680 target=0de1 name=2 isFlipped=YES propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x19d7e330 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x19d793b0 [0x3b84aae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
```

After that I bind them to my scene like this:

```
- (void)bindTexture:(CVOpenGLESTextureRef)texture luma:(BOOL)luma {
    GLKEffectPropertyTexture *t2d = luma ? self.effect.texture2d0 : self.effect.texture2d1;

    if (texture) {
        if (t2d.name != 0) {
            GLuint name = t2d.name;
            glDeleteTextures(1, &name);
        }

        [self updateVertexData];    // this does not perform any OpenGL calls, just deals with arrays in memory

        glBindTexture(CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget(texture), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texture));

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);

        t2d.enabled = GL_TRUE;
        t2d.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
        t2d.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
        t2d.name = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(texture);
    }
}
```

This reads the video, but instead of the texture I'm getting some digital noise on the surfaces, changing as the video progresses. What do I do wrong?

My suspicion is that PixelFormatType in the original pixel buffer is not what I request or expect. Is there a way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the EaglContext?

`EAGLContext * context = [[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2] autorelease];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];`

If yes, the `_videoTextureCache`, is it created successfully ? You should also flush it before creating textures from CVPixelBuffer.

`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, [EAGLContext currentContext], NULL, &_videoTextureCache);`

`CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_videoTextureCache, 0);`

And one last thing, use `NSLog("%d",glGetError());` between each line of code, 0 means no error, another number means there is something wrong.

Hope this helps..